# javascript store data in global variable array(or other better ways)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, electron, global-variables

In electron / node.js, I am trying to do the following

- read in data from excel/csv
- draw data with d3.js
- clean the data (remove duplicate, etc.)
- use the data for some calculation

The pseudo structure of the script looks like below

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
var dialog = remote.dialog;
var dataArr = new array(); //in global scope

function readData(){
    empty(dataArr); //make sure the global array uis empty
    dialog.showOpenDialog(...). //show a file open dialog
    then(...); //read the XLSX/CSV file
    //save the data to dataArr, as an array of object. 
    //[{Time: , pressure: }, ...]

    clean(dataArr);
    draw(dataArr);
}

function empty(arr){ //empty the array
  while(arr.length){
    arr.pop();
  }
}

function clean(res){
    //make sure the time stamp in chronological order
    //make sure there is no duplicated record with same time stamp.
}

function draw(res){
    //draw the array of objects with d3.js
}

function calculate(res){ 
    //use the res to do calculation
    //return some results
}

readData();
calculate(dataArr);
```

the script runs okay. But I found it looks bit messy since the dataArr sometimes were passed to function, sometimes were access as global array.

I saw on internet saying that global variable should be avoid. But in this case, I was not sure what rule or examples I should follow to improve the code, to make it less prone to issues.

Any advise are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be you can create a class whih have all the functionalities as as function like read, calculate and draw etc, and your array will be member of that class and accessable to all the functions

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use global variables for this, because you mixed already global and local variables. Let `readData` return the array.

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
var dialog = remote.dialog;

function readData(){
    var dataArr = new array(); //in local scope
    empty(dataArr); //make sure the local array uis empty
    dialog.showOpenDialog(...). //show a file open dialog
    then(...); //read the XLSX/CSV file
    //save the data to dataArr, as an array of object. 
    //[{Time: , pressure: }, ...]

    clean(dataArr);
    draw(dataArr);
    return dataArr;
}

function empty(arr){ //empty the array
  while(arr.length){
    arr.pop();
  }
}

function clean(res){
    //make sure the time stamp in chronological order
    //make sure there is no duplicated record with same time stamp.
}

function draw(res){
    //draw the array of objects with d3.js
}

function calculate(res){ 
    //use the res to do calculation
    //return some results
}

calculate(readData());
```